# collecting terms in a Differential Equation in Maple

Tags: maple

Is there anyway to make maple collect terms in a differential equation? say for example 
$\dot{y}+y=3\dot{y}-7y$  so I get automatically $2\dot{y}-8y=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[> s:=y'(x)+y(x)=3y'(x)-7y(x):
   t:=lhs(s)-rhs(s);


                                -2y'(x)+8y(x)=0
```